# ANTLR4 specific characters in specific places

Tags: regex, string, antlr, antlr4

I'm using ANTLR4 for a project but I've been tasked with something I'm not quite grasping. I have have a lexer rule tokenize something that starts with either and underscore or a letter, can't start with 'xml' and can contain periods, dashes, letters, digits and underscores. How would I make sure the beginning is a letter or an underscore and also be sure that it isn't 'xml'?

Comment: The question is very abstract. Can you give some specific examples?

Comment: I guess specifically how would you go about recognizing a string that starts with an underscore or letter but doesn't start with the letters 'xml' together. So it would accept '_hello' and 'hello' but not 'xmlhello'

Comment: You can use a negative look-ahead regex pattern while defining your token. Ex: ^(?!xml).+ will match anything that does not start with xml

Comment: @Rnet ANTLR doesn't support regex patterns.

Comment: @Alex5775 show us what you have so far. What did you try to solve that problem?

Comment: I've got a solution that works, though it is a tad bit long winded\n

Comment: fragment: ELEMENTSPECCHARS: ('.'|'-'|'-'|[0-9]|[A-Z]|[a-z]+);                       fragment ELEMENTCHARS: ((('_'|[a-w]|[y-z]]|[A-W]|[Y-Z)ELEMENTSPECCHARS)|(('x'|'X')('m'|'M')([a-k]|[m-z]|[A-K]|[M-Z]|('.'|'_'|'-'|[0-9]|[a-k]|[m-z]|[A-K]|[M-Z])ELEMENTSPECCHARS)))+;

Comment: Pretty much what I've got going on is ELEMENTSPECCHARS has all of the characters that can be in it after the beginning. Then I have ELEMENTCHARS which first does an _ or not x. which is or'd with x and not m which is or'd with x then m then not l. After each of the three sections I added ELEMENTSPECCHARS although in some places I had to just add the special characters because ELEMENTSPECCHARS had a-z and if, for example, I used it after x then not m, it would still pick up xm because the ELEMENTSPECCHARS allowed it

Answer (score 0):

The grammar:

```
grammar Expr;
prog: word+ EOF;
word : STRING ;
STRING : ~[xml]STRINGCHAR+;
WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;
fragment
STRINGCHAR : [_a-z] ;
```

matches "boy" and "_girl" but not "xmlboy" by using the explicit exclusion ~ operator in the definition of STRING.